# Не запускается программа в с++

Tags: c++

Программа компилируется нормально, но при запуске просто на долю секунды появляется консоль и закрывается. Пробовал вставить `system("pause"); getch();` - все равно не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

http://ideone.com/EZ38dL

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cstring" 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void decToBin(int);
void binToDec (char *);

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3) {
        cout << "Using N 2 or N 10, 2/10 - number system. \nExample: 345 2" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    if(atoi(argv[2])==2){
        decToBin(atoi(argv[1]));
    }
    cout << "You press not number..";
    if(atoi(argv[2])==10){
        binToDec(argv[1]);
    }
    cout << "Number system mb 2 or 10.";
    system ("pause");
    return 0;

}
void decToBin(int num){
    int t=0;
    while(num){
        num=num/2;
        t=num%2;
        cout<<t;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}   

void binToDec (char * c) {
    int rez=0; 
    int a=1;  
    int len=strlen(c); 

    for(int j = 0, k = len; j < len; j++, k-- )      
        if ( c[ j ] == '1' ) rez |= a << k - 1; 
    cout << rez;
};
```

При этом выдает следующее:

```
"ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Users\Roman\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe".
Символы загружены. "ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll". Символы загружены.
"ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll". Символы загружены.
"ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll". Символы загружены.
"ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll". Символы загружены.
"ConsoleApplication2.exe" (Win32). Загружено
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll". Символы загружены. Программа
"[2328] ConsoleApplication2.exe" завершилась с кодом -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Вообще советую в таких программах делать отдельную функцию, которая в себе будет содержать код из main, а в main вызывается эта функция и ретурн 0, тогда вам будет проще найти ошибку).

Comment: А что касается getchar() или system("stop") то они не всегда в конце покажут консольку, лучше 2 раза написать getchar()

Comment: а ты не пробовал ее из консоли запустить-то?

Comment: Запускайте из отдельной консоли и смотрите что пишет. Судя по всему проблемы с параметрами комстроки.

Comment: Ну вот вы столкнулись с такой ерундой. Вопрос первый - в отладчике пробовали пройти? Вопрос второй - ну убедитесь, что она вообще запускается, первой строкой в `main()` вставив вывод типа "Запустился" и тот же `getch()`. Убедились? Пошли дальше - с выводом значений `argc` и `argv[]`. Посмотрели, что не так... Ведь по вопросу видно, что вы ничего не пытались сделать самостоятельно, а сразу - как в детском саду - "застегни штанишки!" Привыкайте застегивать их самостоятельно. Есть отладчик, есть отладочный вывод. Спрашивать, что не так, пока вы не побились над задачей хотя бы пару часов - гм...

Comment: функции пишутся до main и еще лучше в отделный файл.

Answer (score 3):

значит это условие не проходит, попробуй вывести на экран   argc , и поставить паузу до return

```
if(argc != 3) {
    cout << "Using N 2 or N 10, 2/10 - number system. \nExample: 345 2" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй конструкцию

```
while (kbhit())
    getch();
getch();
```

Сам с консольным C++ не работал, но по аналогии с Pascal - сначала очистить буфер клавиатуры, потом ждать нажатия

Comment: `kbhit`? и наверное ещё `#include "conio.h"`? как оно там, в двадцатом веке?

Answer (score 0):

Собрал с помощью gcc  (на warning закрыл глаза...)

```
../untitled/main.cpp:151:9: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int n = 0;
         ^
../untitled/main.cpp: In function ‘void binToDec(char*)’:
../untitled/main.cpp:181:44: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘-’ inside ‘<<’ [-Wparentheses]
         if ( c[ j ] == '1' ) rez |= a << k - 1;
```

Запускал вот так ./untitled 345 2

Вместо system ("pause"); я поставил cin.get(); У меня нет "pause" на linux.

```
001101010
You press not number..Number system mb 2 or 10.
```

Я полагаю вы это делаете это на Windows и возможно совсем не вводите параметры командной строки или у вас тоже нет system ("pause");
Замените system на cin.get();
и после вывода cout делайте std::endl;